# What steps to take to reduce latency in a Stream Processing pipeline that uses Kafka, Flink on Mesos?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, mesos

What steps can one take to reduce latency in a Stream Processing pipeline that uses Kafka, Flink on Mesos?

Answer (score 1):

One specific thing we've found to have a great impact, and is Flink-specific, was [setting the network buffer timeout](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment.html#setBufferTimeout-long-).

By using 0 rather than the default (100) a simple job (single input/output with a sliding window) could go from a median latency of 15ms to 1ms. These are very rough numbers but you get the idea.